# .NetでControlのDockStyle.Topを使ってControlを上に詰めていきたいが、逆になってしまう。

Tags: c#, .net

以下の画像の逆で0が一番上にくるようにしたいのですが、逆になってしまいます。
どのようにプロパティを設定すればうまくいくのでしょうか？

環境: c# .Net Framework 4.8

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                TextBox textBox = new TextBox
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                    Text = i.ToString()
                };

                this.panel1.Controls.Add(textBox);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Add`による通常の挿入では既存の子コントロールより上に配置されてしまうため、解法のような対策があります。

1. コントロールを`Add`した時に`BringToFrontで一番下に持っていく
2. `Controls`は配列なので、任意のコントロールを配列から取得し、`SetChildIndex`で任意のインデックスに挿入する
3. `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`の代わりに`for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)`またはそれと類似のロジックを使用する

**サンプルコード**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                TextBox textBox = new TextBox
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                    Text = i.ToString()
                };

                this.panel1.Controls.Add(textBox);
                // 解法1: コントロールを一番下に持っていく
                textBox.BringToFront();
            }
            // 解法2: インデックスを入れ替えて配置換えする(下はインデックス1と8を入れ替える例)
            var index1 = panel1.Controls[1];
            panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(index1, 8);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            // 解法3: 単純に逆順でコントロールを挿入する
            // ※下記の Range(0, 10).Reverse() と Controls.AddRange は for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) と同様に動作する
            var textBoxes = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Reverse().Select(i => new TextBox { Dock = DockStyle.Top, Text = i.ToString() }).ToArray();
            panel1.Controls.AddRange(textBoxes);
        }
    }
}
```

**参考資料**

[Windowsフォームでコントロールの配置や重なりを調整するには？](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/0505/13/news116.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました!

Answer (score 3):

Panelでの解法はpayanecoさんが回答されているので割愛しますが、他にもTableLayoutPanelやFlowLayoutPanel等のコントロールを決まった並べ方をするのに適したコンテナもありますので、それらを使った方法を紹介しておきます。

```csharp
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                TextBox textBox = new TextBox
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                    Text = i.ToString()
                };

                this.panel1.Controls.Add(textBox);
            }

            //TableLayoutPanel
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                TextBox textBox = new TextBox
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                    Text = i.ToString(),
                    Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                };
                tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, textBox.Height));
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textBox, 0, i);
            }

            //FlowLayoutPanel
            flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                TextBox textBox = new TextBox
                {
                    Width = flowLayoutPanel1.ClientRectangle.Width,
                    Text = i.ToString(),
                    Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                };
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textBox);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 実行結果]

Comment: 今回の件であれば本当はFlowLayoutPanelとかが正しいのですが、今回は導入できないので、今後採用したいと思います!